# Is there any cross browser method of disabling pop-ups (tooltips) for titles of images?

Tags: image, popup, tooltip, gallery

I have built a site with a gallery of images, that you can see [here](http://salliannputman.com/work/oil.html).  I would like to disable all pop-ups (tooltips) for titles of images, so that they don't interfere with the look of the gallery.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `title` and `alt` attributes to an empty string.

You have the following code for one of the images:

```
<a class="oils" href="images/oils/slideshow/1.jpg" title="On the White Table&nbsp&nbsp <span class='inches'>25&quot; x 25&quot;</span>"><img src="images/oils/thumbnails/1.jpg" /></a>
```

Everything inside of the `title` section should go, so that it reads:

```
<a class="oils" href="images/oils/slideshow/1.jpg" title=""><img src="images/oils/thumbnails/1.jpg" /></a>
```

Otherwise, the only thing that comes to my mind is to use **Flash** or **Silverlight** to display the gallery images. There are some customizable galleries available, with varying license agreements.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the titles so that they show in my colorbox overlays.

Comment: In fact, I have found out that I can use the alt tags with colorbox, so this is the workaround.

Comment: Just a note: Firefox shows only the `title`, but IE shows both `title` and `alt` as tooltips over images (preferring title if both are provided).